# Collapsing layout in a tool bar with Images and text and icons in Android

Tags: android, parallax, whatsapp, user-profile, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was trying a custom activity as like Whatsapp Group Profile page, where I need to place , 1 Image in left and two text in a layout to the right of image and two icons in the right. The collapsing layout which is currently available is with Imageview only. I am trying similar to the below orange screenshot where I make my layout in place of Imagview to collapse into the tool bar and when scroll on top the images textview and icons gets transferred from below layout to toolbar in the top. Tried all possible ways, Imageview is there but in layout I couldnt achieve.[image]

Comment: please try to check out the following link may be helpful to you.:https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: Observable ScrollView is using View, Imageview in it I tried it, was not able to place multiple textviews and images and icons in the ObservableScrollview. There is a restrictions

Comment: did find any workaround?

Comment: What I found is use an ImageView & TextView inside the Toolbar component, and dynamicaly scale child Views, Or maybe there is better approach